# How to identify the cell in the table and click on it?

Tags: java, html, selenium

There is a simple table on the page, the first raw are the headers of the columns, the second line/raw are the values that are changed dynamically.

```
<div id = ...>
  <table ...>
    <tbody>
      <tr> ... <tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="x11 x22" nowrap>
             <a class="xl" href="search"> </a> </td>
          <td>...
          <td>...
      ....
```

What is the best way to identify the cell - first column/second line in order to click on it?
Many thanks!

Comment: depends on the rest of the markup, but you could use an xpath of //a[@href='search']... assuming that's unique.  They should really be using unique ids in their markup.

Comment: href is not unique...

Comment: ok, assuming the class isn't unique either, you'd need dom traversal, which is not very ideal.  I would have the engineers add unique ids.

Comment: probably there is a way just to build the Array and click on the element [0,1] for example?

Comment: yes, you could use the same xpath I posted with findElements... (if the page is generated via javascript you need to loop and re-call if stale element exception is thrown)  Assuming the link is always returned by the DOM in the same order, you could then pick an index for it.  Still a very brittle locator though.

Comment: in this case how it will look like? sorry, I'm a junior :)

Comment: remember that Selenium is designed to emulate the end-user.  Ask yourself, "how does the user decide what to click?"  Then design your locator based on that.  There is probably something in the row that indicates which search link to use and you can traverse from there.  (Still better to have a unique ID, though, as the event handler will be based on something like that...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click on the first element then the xpath would be:

```
(//a[@href='search'])[1]
```

and for second element it would be:

```
(//a[@href='search'])[2]
```

and so on..

Full code should be like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@href='search'])[2]"));
element.click();
```

Comment: using find.element ...[2].click() ?

Comment: @BobBolden have updated my answer and have added the code. Please check now